# How to deploy a commit of parse server?

Tags: parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

How do I deploy a specific commit of parse server on AWS EB?

I tried to:

1. Change the `package.json` of parse-server-example to:

   "dependencies": {
      "parse-server": "parse-community/parse-server#commit-hash"
   }
2. Run `npm install`
3. Deploy to AWS EB

The server fails to start with error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/var/app/current/node_modules/parse-server/lib/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:316:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:705:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:969:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:864:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/index.js:10:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/var/app/current/node_modules/parse-server/package.json',
  requestPath: 'parse-server'
```

It works when I don't point the dependency to a commit, but it doesn't work with a commit - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Parse Server GitHub repository, you will see that there is no `lib/` folder over there. The `lib/` is at the `.gitignore` file and you will only find it in the npm package. That's why it fails when you try to install directly from the GitHub repository.

The workaround is:

1. Create a fork of Parse Server repository in your own GitHub account.
2. Clone your own fork.
3. Reset to the commit you need, run `npm install`.
4. Remove the `lib/` folder from `.gitignore`, commit, and push it to your own fork.
5. Try the process you described again but installing from your own GitHub fork.

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks. How is the `lib` folder included in the npm package? Is that a config somewhere in `package.json` or a manual command?

Comment: Since it is listed in package.json files section (https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/package.json#L10), it will be sent to npm everytime we run `npm publish`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `npm install` is not running under `root` but rather under a non-privileged user. Running under `root` will break `npm prepare` step that is required to compile src/ into lib/ using babel.